# MySQL select only using first word of variable

Tags: php, mysql

I am using php and mySQL.  I have a select query that is not working.  My code is:

```
$bookquery = "SELECT * FROM my_books WHERE book_title = '$book' OR book_title_short = '$book' OR book_title_long = '$book' OR book_id = '$book'";
```

The code searches several title types and returns the desired reference most of the time, except when the name of the book starts with a numeral.  Though rare, some of my book titles are in the form "2 Book".  In such cases, the query only looks at the "2", assumes it is a "book_id" and returns the second entry in the database, instead of the entry for "2 Book".  Something like "3 Book" returns the third entry and so forth.  I am confused why the select is acting this way, but more importantly, I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: is there any parsing code for $book before this query?

Comment: I have an escape `$book = mysql_real_escape_string($book);` and a validating clause:  `if (!preg_match("/^[\w\s0-9&\'.]+$/", $book)) die("Database error has prevented execution.");`

Comment: What datatype do you use for your `book_id` column?

Comment: echo your $book value prior to executing the query to make sure that the $book variable is what you think it should be.  You should probably also check to see if $book is numeric and only then append the book_id = '$book' part to your query if it is causing problems.

Comment: I did echo $book both before and after my validating and it was as expected.  Answering Ollie, book_id is a tinyint(2).  If I was to check if $book is numeric, is there a way to do that in the SELECT query or would that be using PHP and then having two SELECT queries, one if numeric and one if not?

Comment: Kaii:  the problem with changing the title to a simple question regarding how mySQL works is that I would also like a suggestion on fixing the problem, as stated in the original post.  Phrasing the post as a question on mySQL function eliminates the need to suggest a fix, pretending that education is the only request (rather than just an appreciated addition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others mention, my PHP allowed both numerical enties and text entries from the browser.  My query was then having a hard time with this, interpreting some of my text entries as numbers by truncating the end.  Thus, my "2 Book" was being interpreted as the number "2" and then being queried to find the second book in the database.  To fix this I just created a simple if statement in PHP so that my queries only looked for text or numbers.  Thus, in my case, my solution was:

```
if(is_numeric($book)){
    $bookquery = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE book_id = '$book'";
}else{
    $bookquery = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE book_title = '$book' OR book_title_short = '$book' OR book_title_long = '$book'";
}
```

This is working great and I am on my way coding happily again.  Thanks @OllieJones and others for your questions and ideas which helped me see I needed to approach the problem differently.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a column in your table with a numeric data type (`INT`, maybe), then your search strategy is going to work strangely for values of `$book` that start with numbers. You have discovered this.

The following expression always returns true in SQL. It's not intuitive, but it's true.

```
99 = '99 Luftballon'
```

That's because, when you compare an integer to a string, MySQL implicitly does this:

```
CAST(stringvalue AS INT)
```

And, a cast of a string beginning with the text of an integer always returns the value of the integer. For example, the value of

```
CAST('99 Luftballon' AS INT)
```

is 99. So you'll get book id 99 if you look for that search term.

It's pointless to try to compare an `INT` column to a text string that doesn't start with an integer, because `CAST('blah blah blah' AS INT)` always returns zero. To make your search strategy work better, you should consider omitting `OR book_id = '$book'` from your search query unless you know that the entirety of `$book` is a number.

Comment: In looking for an answer, do I use a PHP if statement and two different SELECT statements or is there a way to modify the SELECT to avoid this problem?

Comment: Please see my edit.I do think your search strategy could use some conceptual work.

Comment: And thus a PHP if statement with two different SELECT statements?

Comment: you could cast book_id to a string before the comparison, which would prevent the other casting from occurring, but still allow number to number comparisons.  The best answer is to validate whether your input is a numeric or not, and change your query based on that,

Comment: @MarshallTigerus,  Casting `book_id` to a string might work, but it will *guarantee* a full table scan on every search. That will hammer performance.

Comment: Here is a solution I have come up with:  `if(is_numeric($book)){ $bookquery = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE book_id = '$book'"; }else{ $bookquery = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE book_title = '$book' OR book_title_short = '$book' OR book_title_long = '$book'"; }`.  Ollie, if you think that is a good solution, you can add it to your post and I will select your answer.  If you have another suggestion, please add it to your answer.  As my question seeks knowledge and a solution, I cannot pick your post as is.

Comment: @OllieJones I agree its a bad idea, but it would technically work.  Thomas, you should add a search on title (at least one of them) for cases where the book has a number in its title and that's what the user wants to search on (just the number)

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if this is the correct answer for you but it seems like you are searching for only exact values in your select. Have you thought of trying a more generic search for your criteria? Such as...

`$bookquery = "SELECT * FROM my_books WHERE book_title LIKE '".$book."' OR book_title_short LIKE '".$book."' OR book_title_long LIKE '".$book."' OR book_id LIKE '".$book."'"`

If you are doing some kind of searching you might even want to ensure the characters before the search key are found as well like so....

`$bookquery = "SELECT * FROM my_books WHERE book_title LIKE '%".$book."' OR book_title_short LIKE '%".$book."' OR book_title_long LIKE '%".$book."' OR book_id LIKE '%".$book."'"`

The `%` is a special char that looks for allows you to search for the chars you want to search for PLUS any characters before this that aren't in the search criteri... for example `$book = "any"` with a `%` before hand in the query like so, ``` '%".$book."'"`` would return both ```company`and also the word`any` by itself.

If you need to you can add a `%` to the end also like so, `'%".$book."%'"`` and it would do the same for the beginning and end of the search key

Comment: please read questions entirely before writing a misleading answer. OP: `In such cases, the query only looks at the "2", assumes it is a "book_id" and returns the second entry in the database, instead of the entry for "2 Book"`

Comment: `book_id` is obviously of type `INT` which makes this answer wrong.

Comment: I did read the question. That doesn't mean the question was written articulately enough to understand... I took a guess because I wanted to help, not get down-voted and discouraged from helping others... At NO POINT IN TIME, did this person mention needing a comparison operator for a primary or unique key. This seemed like a search question to me....